# How can I programmatically disable options in a select element?

Tags: javascript, html

In my snippet below, when the user selects "Economy" or "First" class from the first dropdown I want only the corresponding seat options to be enabled in the second dropdown.  So, if the user selects "Economy" class in the first dropdown, the first class seating options should be disabled in the second dropdown, and vice versa.  Is there a way to programmatically disable these `<option>`s in the `<select>`?  If so, how?

```js
var $x=document.getElementsByClassName("b").innerHTML;
var $y=document.getElementsByClassName("economy").innerHTML;
var $z=document.getElementsByClassName("first").innerHTML;
function select() {
    console.log("$x ==> ", $x);
    console.log("$y ==> ", $y);
    console.log("$z ==> ", $z);
}
select();
```

```css
.fontstyle {
    font-family: "calibri";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Ticket reservation form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <h1 class="fontstyle"> AIRTICKET RESERVATON FORM</h1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="fontstyle">Customer Name :</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="ENTER NAME" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="fontstyle"> Specify your Class :</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="s1"> <!--select tag starts-->
                        <option class="b">Select</option>
                        <option class="b" onchange="select()">Economy</option>
                        <option class="b" onchange="select()">FirstClass</option>
                    </select> <!--select tag closed-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="fontstyle"> Select your Seat :</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option disabled>Economy class </option> <!--economy class seats-->
                        <option class="economy">1</option>
                        <option class="economy">2</option>
                        <option class="economy">3</option>
                        <option class="economy">4</option>
                        <option class="economy">5</option>
                        <option disabled>First class </option> <!-- first class seats-->
                        <option class="first">6</option>
                        <option class="first">7</option>
                        <option class="first">8</option>
                        <option class="first">9</option>
                        <option class="first">10</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There used to be a tag called "enabled" that you would set-up as false and true on stuff.

Comment: @israel.zinc there is nothing like "enabled", it is disabled. see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  I've cleaned up this question as best as possible.  First, I tried to make the wording clearer-- please review.  Also, there were _many_ code errors in your code before your question even would be relevant-- you were using the wrong HTML comment syntax, using markup in the JS/CSS blocks, misspelled `getElementsByClassName`, low-value alerts, no indents, etc.  Please review, and check your code carefully before posting in the future. Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```
<select id="selector" onchange="myFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('class'));">
<option>Select</option>
<option disabled>Economy class </option> //economy class seats
<option class="economy">1</option>
<option class="economy" >2</option>
<option class="economy" >3</option>
<option class="economy" >4</option>
<option class="economy" >5</option>
<option disabled>First class </option>    // first class seats
<option class="first" >6</option>
<option class="first" >7</option>
<option class="first" >8</option>
<option class="first" >9</option>
<option class="first" >10</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction(val) {
    var op = document.getElementById("selector").getElementsByClassName(val);
    for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
        op[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
```